# bucket a multi select picklist within a report?

Tags: reporting, formula

Quick question

Can you bucket a multi select picklist within a report ?

If so how can you do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, multi select picklists are notorious for being hard to report off of. You may be able to create a formula field that does some of your bucketing and then use that in reporting, but you won't be able to bucket directly on the field. See this KB on reporting with multi-select picklists: http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004482&language=en_US.

Comment: Thats what i thought, but didnt want to create new fields